# Getting multiple DbContexts to use Migrations with the same database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

Based on a sample MVC5 project I'm trying to learn the proper way to handle migrations.

In the root directory I have a folder called "DbContexts" with two Contextes.

First one: IdentityContext.cs

```
    public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public IdentityContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    { }
}
```

then I have a folder called IdentityMigrations with the Configuration.cs

```
    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TryFive.Web.DbContexts.IdentityContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        MigrationsDirectory = @"DbContexts\IdentityMigrations";
    }

    protected override void Seed(TryFive.Web.DbContexts.IdentityContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
}
```

Then I have MyContexts with similar properties.

When I try to run the "Update-Database" command I get this error message: `The type 'TryFive.Web.DbContexts.IdentityContext' does not inherit from 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'. Migrations configuration types must extend from 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'.`

Any idea on how to fix this or a better way to do this DbContext stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: If you are just doing a sample project to learn migrations as you say, stick to one DbContext. Keep it simple - merge your entities into one DbContext that inherits from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`

Delete your existing migrations folders you've created - and re "enable-migrations" after deleting your second DbContext. This will help you to continue learning migrations, instead of learning how to use two DbContext's in one project.

Also, @Lajos, I'm not sure which MVC you are talking about, but my DbContext's have never inherited from DbMigrationsConfiguration - they inherit from DbContext, or IdentityDbContext. What you are referring to is the MigrationsConfiguration class that gets generated when issuing "enable-migrations" on a project. It is used for generating migrations and seeding data.

Comment: Ok so you're saying that its okay to add my models to the default DbContext?  Every sample I've seen they keep the ASP.NET Identity to the default then create their own DbContext that calls the same database and I was having issues telling Migrations to accept both DbContexts.

Comment: Yes it should be fine. They just give you a default DbContext out of the box - you can modify it as needed, but you shouldn't need to create a second one. I've seen some of those posts about using seperate IdentityContext and other context but to me it is just overcomplicated unless you are dealing with certain scenarios.

Comment: For the question heading, I'm not sure you're helping search engines with this answer. Haha.